# How to SELECT NOT IN with Zend and eliminate matching rows

Tags: mysql, zend-framework

Here is what I am trying to do.  I have a table that has medals in it.  There is a `user_id` column and a `medal_id` column.  People with the same `user_id` have multiple medals, so my data looks like this:

```
user_id | medal_id
101       1
123       2
101       2
144       1
144       2
....
```

I need to select (with Zend) all of the medals with, say, a `medal_id` of 2.  Using `SELECT ... NOT IN` will eliminate rows 2,3 and 5 from my selection.  But I also need to eliminate the other two rows since they have a `user_id` that matches the rows I'm trying to eliminate from my selection.  In other words, I'm trying to eliminate rows with a `user_id` that matches anything in my `NOT IN` array.  (There will be an array of medals in the selection.)  Here is what I am thinking:

```
$db->select()->from('medals')
   ->where('medal_id NOT IN (?)', $medalIdsArray)
   ->where('user_id NOT IN (?)', _________);
```

But I have no idea what to put for the blank.  I'm wondering if I need some kind of subselect.  I just don't know where to start?  Can someone help?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A subselect of

```
SELECT DISTINCT user_id FROM medals WHERE medal_id =2
```

gives a list of all users who have the medal you want to exclude. Then you can select all remaining rows:

```
SELECT user_id, medal_id FROM medals WHERE user_id NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT user_id FROM medals WHERE medal_id =2)
```

To put this into Zend Object notation, this would convert to

```
$sub_select = $zdb->select()
              ->from("medals", array("distinct user_id"))
              ->where("medal_id = ?", '2');
$select = $zdb->select()
          ->from("medals", array("user_id", "medal_id"))
          ->where("user_id NOT IN ?", $sub_select);
print $select->__toString();
```

This will print out the query shown above.

Comment: I had to modify your syntax slightly, but it appears to be working.  Thanks so much @elie.